# problem with printing Arabic content in python

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8, arabic

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
input,SL
السلام,O
عليكم,O
.,O
السلام,O
عليكم,O
و,O
رحمة,O
الله,O
.,O
السلام,O
عليكم,O
و,O
رحمة,O
الله,O
وبركاته,O
.,O
مرحبا,O
.,O
```

I'm trying to print it using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv("trying11.csv")


print(data)
```

The output looks like this:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbvD7.png)

How can I print Arabic letters?

Comment: You'll have to find out what encoding was used for saving the original CSV file. Then pass this as `pd.read_csv("trying11.csv", encoding=...)`.

Comment: I solved the problem. I used pyCharm instead of the terminal.